# Graph built by using wiktionary data

Tags: wordnet, wiktionary

In the article "AUTOMATIC WORDNET CONSTRUCTION USING
WIKIPEDIA DATA" (link: http://www.openaccess.hacettepe.edu.tr:8080/xmlui/bitstream/handle/11655/9372/10261721.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y), in section "4.4.2. Multilingual Graph Method", author mention about using graph which is built using the Wiktionary data to calculate the weight of word to word edge. The problem is I can not find that graph anywhere on the Internet. Please help me if you know any information about Wiktionary graph or a method to build it.

Answer (score 0):

You are welcome to look at our work:
Krizhanovsky, Andrew (2017): Russian Wiktionary thesaurus in Gephi format (20160210) with screenshots. figshare. https://dx.doi.org/10.6084/m9.figshare.4539143.v1